# The Area51 page of EOSIO beta looks frozen

Tags: bug, status-completed

The beta site originated from [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/116927/eosio) on Area51.
Right after start, the numbers there looked meaningful, but currently, the number of daily visits is 0 for a few days, which can't be right.

Is this a bug?
Should this page actually reflect the current state of the site?

Comment: Currently, the incorrect stats with 0 visits/day are even displayed on the right of the main [eosio.stackexchange.com] page, even for users not logged in. It is a bug, sure. Sad that no person able to fix it seems to care, for a month already.

Comment: I pinged someone on the dev team to check on the status of this.

Answer (score 5):

They found the cause: turned out we had the wrong Google Analytics key specified in the site settings. It was reset it to the correct value. The stats should start tracking again shortly. Sorry about that!