# The "site stats" sidebar is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed

The sidebar with site stats at the right shows wrong numbers.

[image: current site stats]

For starters, the 0 visitors/day is clearly wrong.
I've already [asked about it](https://eosio.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28/151) with respect to Area51 stats, but got no response in a month (how come?).
This now is worse, it's the same buggy data shown on the main site page, even for users not logged in: that is, to everyone.

The other data seems to also be lagging behind.
For example, it shows 1971 users, but [user 1971](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/users/1971) was added three days ago, and there is now [user 1980](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/users/1980).
That may be explained by account deletion though.

Comment: I pinged someone on the dev team to check on the status of this.

Answer (score 3):

They found the cause: turned out we had the wrong Google Analytics key specified in the site settings. It was reset it to the correct value. The stats should start tracking again shortly. Sorry about that!